# Where in R code should I use set.seed() function (specifically, before shuffling or after)?

Tags: r, neural-networks, random-generation

I've been using the set.seed() function to reproduce same results on multiple runs. However, I don't understand where to use the function.
the reason I'm asking this is because if I use the function before shuffling the data, it is producing different results than if I use the function after shuffling.

In my case, I have first used set.seed() after shuffle here :

```
data <- read.csv("F:/winequality-white.csv")
#shuffle
data <- data[sample(1:nrow(data)),]
set.seed(123)
data$quality = as.factor(data$quality)
div = 0.7
index <- 1:nrow(data)
position <- sample(index, trunc(nrow(data) * div))
test <- data[-position,]
train <- data[position,]
result = data[nrow(test),]
result$pred = -1
model_nnet <- nnet(as.factor(quality) ~ ., data=train, size=10, maxit=1000)
pred<- predict(model_nnet, test, type="class")
```

It gives the result

```
    predicted
true   3   4   5   6   7   9
   3   0   1   3   1   0   0
   4   0   5  27  17   1   0
   5   1   6 259 155   3   0
   6   0   3 152 431  79   2
   7   0   0   5 164  98   1
   8   0   0   1  26  25   0
   9   0   0   0   2   2   0
```

And on running using set.seed() after shuffle

```
data <- read.csv("F:/winequality-white.csv")
set.seed(123)    
#shuffle
data <- data[sample(1:nrow(data)),]
data$quality = as.factor(data$quality)
div = 0.7
index <- 1:nrow(data)
position <- sample(index, trunc(nrow(data) * div))
test <- data[-position,]
train <- data[position,]
result = data[nrow(test),]
result$pred = -1
model_nnet <- nnet(as.factor(quality) ~ ., data=train, size=10, maxit=1000)
pred<- predict(model_nnet, test, type="class")
table(true=test$quality, predicted=pred)
```

produces the result

```
    predicted
true   4   5   6   7
   3   1   5   1   0
   4   7  27  15   1
   5   3 234 179   4
   6   2 135 480  57
   7   1  10 169  92
   8   0   0  33  13
   9   0   0   0   1
```

As you can see the results and accuracy are different. I just want to know where exactly to use the set.seed() function to produce the best results. In the above case, it should be either after I shuffle the data or before that.
Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=set.seed

Comment: [Searching for "seed" in the "random-generation" tag is probably more useful.](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=[random-generation]+seed+is%3Aq)

Comment: You reset the RNG seed to ensure reproducible results and to control variation in results, e.g., for sensitivity analyses - not to produce better results. Ideally, your algorithm's results should be insensitive to the specific choice of seed. So the answer is: you should reset the seed for any code block where you want the results to be reproducible.

Answer (score 2):

You use set.seed to reproduce your results. Therefore you have to use this function before you generate the random variables. This means:

```
> set.seed(1)
> sample(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),4)
[1] 3 4 5 7
> sample(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),4)
[1] 3 9 8 5
```

If you do the same again, you get the same numbers.

```
> set.seed(1)
> sample(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),4)
[1] 3 4 5 7
```

If you execute your code again, you will get in your first case the same output, and in the second one a different.

EDIT: To make it clear: set.seed means to initialize your generator of random variables.

Answer (score 2):

Something to understand is that the usual random number generators employed by computers are **NOT** actually random! They generate numbers that appear to be random, but deep down, computerized "random number" generators (with rare exception) are based upon deterministic algorithms.

The generator has some internal state $\mathbf{x}_t$. Every time $t$ you generate a random number, essentially two things happen:

- It generates the random number $z_t$ based upon the state: $z_t = f(\mathbf{x}_t)$
- It advances the state to the next state: $\mathbf{x}_{t+1} = g(\mathbf{x}_t)$

What you are doing when you call `set_seed` is that you are setting the internal state variable $\mathbf{x}$. From that point forward, you get a deterministic sequence of "random numbers" based upon that initial state. For example:

- Set the seed to $x$
- Generate 100 "random" numbers.
- Set the seed to $x$ again
- Generate 100 "random" numbers.

And the two sequences of "random" numbers will be the same.

Answer (score -1):

`set.seed()` has to be used every time to get a reproducible result. Examine the example below:

```
set.seed(101) # set 101 as seed
rnorm(5) # generate 5 std normal random numbers N(0,1)
rnorm(5) # another 5, but without set.seed()
set.seed(101)
rnorm(5) # with set.seed(); result same as the first
set.seed(101)
sample(x = 1:100, size = 10) # with set.seed()
sample(x = 1:100, size = 10) # without set.seed()
set.seed(101)
sample(x = 1:100, size = 10) # agian with set.seed()
```

**So every time you shuffle, you need to use `set.seed()` beforehand**.